# Blender doesn't render my animation

Tags: rendering, animation, cycles-render-engine

I'm a beginner in Blender. I created a simple animation with [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oysCSbhXYBo) tutorial, but i cannot render it.

I see this gray rectangle instead of the viewport every time in the render viewport. I'm using Cycles engine. Can someone help me?

[Link](https://files.fm/f/cg5jsvpuf) to my blend file:

Blender version: 3.0

My setup:

Lenovo Legion

CPU AMD Ryzen 7 5800H

GPU RTX 3070, OS Windows 11 21H2

[image: gray rectangle]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to do a test render, but initializing was taking too long, so I reduced the render resolution to 25%, and then it worked. Though the memory usage is huge:

[image: test render]

6GB of memory seems overkill for that scene, and it probably wouldn't have worked at full resolution.

I see you have several meshes with ocean modifiers with the render resolution set to 32. That would generate meshes of over 8,3 million triangles, and this for each object with ocean modifiers. So with your three oceans, that's almost 25 million triangles to display and move around each frame.

It's a lot to handle for Blender, so probably reduce that way down. Each additional resolution level adds exponentially more than the previous level, so you don't need to go high in the first place.

Comment: Thank you very much!